# Visual Basic libraries on C# code

Tags: c#, file, parsing, csv

Is it incorrect or frowned up to use Visual Basic libraries on C# code?

One particular example is the CSV parser which exists for VB but not for C#.
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO for TextFieldParser

I am sure there is other examples. Of course there are ways to do the same in C# but would require writing more code, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This is an opinionated question however you can use `MicroSoft.VisualBasic` Class lib inside C# for instance for `InputBox` control works well in VB.NEt but C# .net does not provide the same functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole *point* of .NET (well, one major point) is that it doesn't matter what language things are written in! So calling a VB library from C# is no big deal.

`TextFieldParser` is perfectly safe and reasonable to use from C#. It's part of the default Framework install. Use it!

"Why reinvent the wheel?" -- Exactly!